# CheckedTextView: how to get setOnCheckedChangedListener()

Tags: android, checkedtextview

Is it possible to get an `onCheckChangedListener` for the checkbox of a checkedtexview?

It is much more efficient compared to setting an `onClickListener` for the checkedtexview.
so pelase don't tell me to define a checkbox.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it is more efficient?

Comment: At least, it is more efficient to work with. For a start: you wont have to define and keep track of a ismyboxchecked! boolean.

Comment: @Campiador You dont need to create that boolean. `CheckedTextView` has a method called `isChecked()`, which you can use in the `OnClickListener`

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Ok thanks, I know, I mean an external mIsChecked for maintaining the box state during screen flips and likewise situations. Please help me on the question topic if you can.